# How can I create a table in ksqldb.io without causing a syntax error?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

The state of flux ksql is curently in makes it really hard to understand which feature is supported/rejected/mandatory/optional in which release. Confluent's documentation without explicit version references doesn't make it better so I am stuck here:

```
create table gtest (ID varchar PRIMARY KEY) with (kafka_topic = 'g', value_format='avro');
```

creates a syntax error

```
line 1:32: mismatched input 'PRIMARY' expecting {',', ')'}
Statement: create table gtest (ID varchar PRIMARY KEY) with (kafka_topic = 'g', value_format='avro');
Caused by: line 1:32: mismatched input 'PRIMARY' expecting {',', ')'}
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException
```

Topic is available, created with schema, it can import data from an oracle database, stream can be created, all fine. But this table won't get created contrary to all documentation I found. What am I missing here?

I am using Confluent 5.5.1, built form tarball, ksql 0.11.0 built from confluentinc's docker image.

Schemas:

```
{
  "subject": "g-key",
  "version": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ConnectDefault\",\"namespace\":\"io.confluent.connect.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"ID\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"
}


{
  "subject": "g-value",
  "version": 1,
  "id": 6,
  "schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ConnectDefault\",\"namespace\":\"io.confluent.connect.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"GT_ID\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"int\",\"connect.type\":\"int8\"}},{\"name\":\"BARCODE\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"LP_ID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"IN_G_ID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"RS\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"NSP\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"EINT\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"EINDATE\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"long\",\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}},{\"name\":\"MKZ\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"AKM\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"AKT\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"LZTB\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"long\",\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}},{\"name\":\"TE\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"QU\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"ZWIZ\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"ENDL\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"FREIP\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"HRLZ\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"PERFZ\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"EINLO\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"long\",\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"UMKJN\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"KOLR\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"int\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"LA_ID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"VIEW_B\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null}]}"
}
```

Any hint welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Current version of CP is 5.5.1 and as [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#ksqldb) says it has kqslDB v0.7.1
but 'PRIMARY KEY' syntax is available starting from ksqlDB v0.10

Comment: looks like @mjahr is building .11 from source

Comment: I installed KSQLDB Server separately as docker image. The 0.7 version of the package was my first shot but it even more deviated from the current ksqldb documentation.